# Return numbers after first three letters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I have several project codes, which I need do de-code the first three letters e.f. FIT385950 should be: 385950..

My issue is that the numbers are not always the same lenght..

FIT484
FIT4503032
etc.

How Can I do this?

Comment: Apart from formulas you can use text to columns with fixed bounds and skip first column when pasting results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May try use `LEFT()` and `LEN()` functions

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-3)
```

Comment: This works, but it made me realize a new issue. I also have 'GIT-projects' which im not interested in. Can I make it "FIND" "FIT" only, and then return?

Comment: @Aabo of course, try `=IF(LEFT(A2,3)="FIT", RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-3),"")`

Answer (score 1):

We can try using the `MID()` function here.  Assuming your data be in cell `A1`:

```
=MID(A1, 4, LEN(A1) - 3)
```

If you want to target only strings which begin with the prefix `FIT`, then use `IF()`:

```
=IF(MID(A1, 1, 3)="FIT", MID(A1, 4, LEN(A1) - 3), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to extract number in find with prefix "`FIT`" only and without `IF()` :

```
=MID(A1,FIND("FIT",A1&"FIT")+3,LEN(A1))
```